# Getting error while knitting. output generated in log file but not able to convert into pdf

Tags: r, knitr, miktex

While knitting .Rmd, I am getting this error:

```
! Sorry, but C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
! The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
!   C:/Users/seema.desai/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log
! You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.
Error: LaTeX failed to compile heavy_users_groupwise.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See heavy_users_groupwise.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

i tried to restart R, run it again but it throws the same error